# Waiting for the end of a recursive readdir function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, bluebird

i'm using a recursive readdir to read the whole file tree of a directory to put it into a database.

My problem is that i'm trying to stop the next lines of code while the whole readdir / insert to the database isn't finished.

I was looking for a solution in promises but at the first call of my function (so in the first folder of the tree) the promise is fulfilled...

Any idea ?

```
function readsousdir(path, db, db2) {
    var Datastore = require('nedb');
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readdir(path + '\\', function (err, files) {
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.stat(path + '\\' + file, function (err, stats) {
                var foldertrue = stats.isDirectory();
                var filetrue = stats.isFile() == true;
                if (foldertrue == true) {
                    var doc;
                    doc = folderdb(path + '\\' + file);
                    db2.insert(doc);
                    readsousdir(path + '\\' + file, db, db2);
                }
                if (filetrue) {
                    doc = pistedb(path + '\\' + file, []);
                    db.insert(doc);

                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what type of object is the `db` object from?

Comment: It's a nedb Datastore : https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb

Comment: What promise library are you using ?

Comment: I can use Q or bluebird, as your exemple use bluebird i'll use it too. You're all damn fast ! (much more than me, i'm trying to understand all your answers). Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using BlueBird, you could use [`reduce`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#reducefunction-reducer--dynamic-initialvalue---promise):

```
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

function readsousdir(path, db, db2) {
    var Datastore = require('nedb');
    return fs.readdirAsync(path + '\\').reduce(function(_, file){
        return fs.statAsync(path + '\\' + file)
        .then(function(stats){
            var foldertrue = stats.isDirectory();
            var filetrue = stats.isFile() == true;
            if (foldertrue == true) {
                var doc;
                doc = folderdb(path + '\\' + file);
                db2.insert(doc);
                return readsousdir(path + '\\' + file, db, db2)
            }
            if (filetrue) {
                doc = pistedb(path + '\\' + file, []);
                db.insert(doc);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Supposing your db library returns promises and you want to wait for the insertion, you would do

```
function readsousdir(path, db, db2) {
    var Datastore = require('nedb');
    return fs.readdirAsync(path + '\\').reduce(function(_, file){
        return fs.statAsync(path + '\\' + file)
        .then(function(stats){
            var foldertrue = stats.isDirectory();
            var filetrue = stats.isFile() == true;
            if (foldertrue == true) {
                var doc;
                doc = folderdb(path + '\\' + file);
                return db2.insert(doc).then(function(){
                    return readsousdir(path + '\\' + file, db, db2)
                });
            }
            if (filetrue) {
                doc = pistedb(path + '\\' + file, []);
                return db.insert(doc);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: If you're using Bluebird, why wouldn't you promisify `fs.readdir()` rather than use the callback?

Comment: As your comment indicates, this code really shouldn't be doing `fs.statSync()` either.  That should likely be async.  And, I know this wasn't part of the question, but I suspect the `db.insert(doc)` and `db2.insert(doc)` likely need appropriate error handling which would definitely add to the complexity of a full solution.

Comment: @jfriend00 I hadn't immediately noticed the call to stat so I changed strategy in the middle...

Comment: Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\A ECOUTER\undefined'
    at Error (native)

Comment: it seems that it loses the "file" (undefined) on the first loop, the faulty javascript file is this one : bluebird\js\main\captured_trace.js:478

Comment: @dinfo Of course, I forgot something. file is the second argument received by the callback. I edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first is working! (i'll look closer on the second, i'm beginning and it's a bit longer for me ;))

Comment: Why all the `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: The whole `== true` are useless.